# How to insert image data from xml into xsl template?

Tags: xml, xslt, xls, apache-fop

I am converting `xml` to `PDF` with an `xsl` template, using `Apache-FOP`.

I have the following xml structure:

```
<image>
    <type>image/png</type>
    <data>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...</data>
</image>
```

And a template like:

```
<fo:external-graphic content-height="60pt" height="auto" width="auto"
                     src="url(data:<type>;base64,<data>)"/>
```

How do I insert data and type into the template?

Is there a better way to insert image as data from an `xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is inside of an `xsl:template match="image"`, to populate the attribute value from the child elements, use attribute value templates `src="url(data:{type};base64,{data})"`.